# Finding the maximum for this function.

Tags: calculus

I am having difficulty finding a constant k such that k is larger than$ \frac{(logn)^b}{n} $ where b is a constant. Is there a way I can rewrite this?

Comment: Since $\,\frac{\log^bn}{n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0\,$ for any $\,b\,$ , do you want a bound for all $\,n\,$?

Comment: Yes. I want a constant that is greater than the maximum of the function. For example for 1/n, the maximum is 1, so k would be 1

Comment: Is there an asymptotic maximum to this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

noting the title and assuming that you want b>0 and n>1 and using ln instead of log

$$f'(n,b) = \frac{(b-ln(n))(ln ~n)^{(b-1)}}{n^2} = 0$$
$$b*(ln ~n)^{(b-1)} = (ln~ n)^b$$
$$n = e^b$$

$$ln(e^b)^b/(e^b) = b^b/(e^b)$$

$$k> \frac{b^b}{e^b}$$

does that work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Let me see if I understand your question correctly.  You have $b$, a constant. You have the function $f(n) = \frac{\ln^b(n)}{n}$.

You wish you maximize the function $f(n)$ with respect to $n$, then find a $k$ that is larger than that maximum.

---

$f_n(n) = \frac{b\ln^{b-1}(n) - \ln^b(n)}{n^2} = 0$

$\therefore b = \ln(n) $

And so we know $n = e^b$ is the value that optimizes the function.  Since there is only the one optimization point Im going to assume, based on the question, that this is a maximum.  At the optimization point we have a value, a maximum, of $f(e^b) = (\frac{b}{e})^b$.

And value $k\gt (\frac{b}{e})^b$ will produce your result.